# Content is not displaying in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

I am trying to display content in my `UITableView` in my `UIViewController`.

My table view is in a regular view called `todayView` which is in a `UIViewController` called `Calendar`
I connected the `datasource` and `delegate` to `Calendar` and added all of the methods for table view, but it still doesn't work.
Currently, my code looks like this
Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
@implementation SecondViewController {
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
}

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    self.dateLabel.text = dateString;


    Event *e1 = [[Event alloc] init];
    e1.name = @"All School Mass";
    e1.time = @"All Day";

    [tableData addObject:e1];

    Event *e2 = [[Event alloc] init];
    e2.name = @"Tennis - Moreau Catholic vs James Logan";
    e2.time = @"4:00 pm at Moreau Catholic";

    [tableData addObject:e2];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        //Create your cell
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    //Configure your cell
    Event *event = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = event.name;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you initialized that tableData mutable Array ?
i think you hav'nt initialized it thats why its all happening.

Please allocate it

tableData= [NSMutableArray array];
than add some objects .

otherwise tableData.count will return always zero.
so no data will be display.

Answer (score 0):

You may forget this method
`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;`
you can implement it and return 1.